# Creating a 3D numpy array with different data types

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a numpy 3-dimensional array that would be a representation of a texas holdem starting hand matrix with corresponding frequencies for performing certain action in a given spot facing some action (for example UTG facing 3-bet from BU).

If you google preflop hand chart you will find thousands of pictures with hand matrices where fold/call/raise as actions are usually indicated by different colors.

I want to represent that in a numpy 3-dimensional array **WITH DIFFERENT DATA TYPES** with 13 rows x 13 columns and any number of "layers" in 3rd dimension depending on number of actions I want to store, for example I might want to store min raise/raise 3x/raise all in/call/fold. For that I would need different data types for the first element of "3rd dimension" and integers or decimals for other layers of 3rd dimension. First layer would be just the text representing starting hand combination (like "AA" or "89suited" and the rest of the cells would be numeric.

I created an image for easier understanding of what I mean.

Green layer would be string data type representing the hand matrix.

Yellow layer would be number of combinations of that starting hand.

Blue layer would be for example how often you raise. If you look at the picture you would see that AKs gets raised 81% of the time while AQs 34% of the time.

To get green layer you would type:

```
array[:,:,0]
```

Yellow layer would be:

```
array[:,:,1]
```

ans so forth.

I know how to create a solution for my problem using JSON, dictionary or some other tool but in the interests of learning and challenges I would like to solve that using numpy.
I also know how to create an array of all text and I could store numbers as strings, retrieve them as such and convert them but that solution is also unsatisfactory.

Plus it would be beneficial to have it as numpy array because of all the slicing and summing that you can do on an array, like knowing the total number of hands that get raised which in this case would be sum of (number of combos, i.e. layer 2 * frequencies of individual starting hands getting raised).

[image]

So the question boils down to how to create a 3d numpy array from the start with different data types?

Comment: IMHO, you are using a wrong tool here. A numpy array is just a wrapper around a C array, so all elements **must** have same type. Maybe pandas DataFrame where each column has its type (and is backed by a different numpy array) could be better.

Comment: I agree with Serge. If you dont want to use pandas you can also make a list of three arrays. Or even a list of lists.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion on my own when trying to implement the actual solution for myself, I just found this whole spiel with numpy interesting. But if you all agree that it is pointless I guess I'll drop it.

Comment: By defining a compound dtype you can make a `structured array`:   https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.rec.html.  Most examples show a 1d array with multiple fields, but it could certainly be 2d.  But making separate arrays with different dtypes is often just as good.  A `pandas` dataframe can have different dtypes for each column, but you can't layer a 2d array on top of that.